# Probability that tossing two dice results in two different even numbers

Tags: probability

> There are two different cubes of which sides are numbered from 1 to 6. If two cubes are tossed, what is the probability that two different even numbers are shown?
>
> Answer : $1/6$

Please explain how to reach this answer. I know that total outcomes are 36 but not quite sure how to get to the probability of two different even numbers.

Comment: This is about the fourth question you've posted in three hours with no evidence of a shred of effort to work out the problem yourself.

Comment: Well these are questions that I have worked on in the past and wasn't able to get the answers for, which I'm posting on a single day. I've followed the one question per every 20 minutes rule, so I don't see why you have a problem with this.

Answer (score 4):

List your outcomes. You have: $(2, 4), (2, 6), (4, 6)$, and then the same could happen just switching the ordering on the cubes: $(4, 2), (6, 2), (6, 4)$. This gives you the probability $6/36 = 1/6$ as desired.

Answer (score 1):

There are $6$ possibilities for the first dice roll, of which $3$ are even. Given this, there are $6$ possibilities for the second dice roll, of which $2$ are even *and different from the first dice roll*. This gives $$\frac{3}{6} \cdot \frac{2}{6} = \frac{1}{6}$$

Answer (score 1):

Great on the total outcomes. Now, before we talk about the numerator, let's understand one thing. The ORDER in which the final outcome arises is important. That is, call the cubes $C_{1}$ and $C{2}$. Therefore, $C_{1}$ rolling 2 and $C_{2}$ rolling 4 is DIFFERENT from $C_{1}$ rolling 4 and $C_{2}$ rolling 2. I state this so you realise that you must be using permutations not combinations. Furthrmore, by the multiplication principle the number of favourable outcomes is $3\times 2 = 6$. There are 3 even numbers that the first cube can roll. After this there are only 2 remaining for the second cube such that the even numbers are unique. Thus,

$$\mathcal{P}(E)=\frac{6}{36} = \frac{1}{6}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Probability of two different even numbers =
Probability of both even * Probability of both different given they are both even.

Probability of both even is $\dfrac12\times\dfrac12=\dfrac14$.

Given they are both even there are $3$ possible even numbers: $2, 4, 6$.

$$\text{Probability both different} = \text{Probability the second is not the same as the first} = \frac23$$

So $$\text{Probability of two different even numbers} = \frac14\times\frac23=\frac16$$